# Connection of the likelihood function and sufficient statistics

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Casella Berger has the following statement:

> A function $T(x)$ of the sample is specified and the principle
> (?sufficiency?) states that if $x$ and $y$ are two sample points with
> $T(x) = T(y)$, then the same inference about $\theta$ should be made
> whether $x$ or $y$ is observed. The function $T(x)$ is a sufficient
> statistic when the Sufficiency Principle is used. The "value" of
> $T(x)$ is the set of all likelihood functions proportional to
> $L(\theta|x)$ if the Likelihood principle is used.

I have a hard time digesting this.

1. Why does C&B refer to some random function and says that if the values are equal, we have to assume the inference about $\theta$ is the same. Then C&B mentions that "it would be called a sufficient statistic". Isn't it visa versa? In C&B the Sufficiency principle actually requires that $T(x)$ is a sufficient statistic, and only then the evidence equality for $x, y$ follows. What is wrong here?
2. What does C&B mean by **The "value" of $T(x)$ is the set of all likelihood functions proportional to $L(\theta|x)$ if the Likelihood principle is used.** ? What do likelihood functions have to do with a sufficient statistic $T(x)$, and how are they proportional? Also, why are we talking about "functions" when the likelihood for a particular parameter $\theta$ is actually a value.

Comment: Can you mention where in the textbook you found this passage?

Comment: @angryavian page 296, second edition, right at the beginning of section 6.4 about equivariance principle.

Comment: One way of stating the sufficiency principle is that if $T(X)$ is a sufficient statistic for $θ$, then any inference about $θ$ should depend on the sample $X$ only through the value $T(X)$.  Looking at this from the other direction, if inferences about $θ$ only depend on the value of $T(X)$ and any other information about $X$ does not affect the inference then $T(X)$ is sufficient.

Comment: @Henry i know, this is exactly how sufficiency is stated in C&B. But i cannot figure what his paragraph above means then ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are trying to clarify that the sufficiency principle and the likelihood principle are similarly structured. They state a general template for a principle as follows. (I will use $S$ instead of $T$ so as not to conflate with the notation used when stating the sufficiency principle.)

> **General principle based on function $S$.** If $x$ and $y$ are two sample points with $S(x)=S(y)$, then the same inference about $\theta$ should be made whether $x$ or $y$ is observed.

For different choices of $S$ you will get different principles. The authors explain how the sufficiency principle and the likelihood principles are special cases of the above general principle for certain choices of $S$.

- If $S:=T$ where $T$ is a sufficient statistic, then the above principle becomes the sufficiency principle.
- If $S$ maps $x$ to the set $\{c L(\theta \mid x) : c > 0\}$, then the above principle becomes the likelihood principle. (Try to convince yourself that with this definition, $S(x)=S(y)$ means that $L(\theta \mid x)$ and $L(\theta \mid y)$ are proportional.)

Comment: could you clarify: in example 2, is it the set of all functions, or set of values? If it is a set of values, then it is generated by $c > 0$, but what is $\theta$ then?

Comment: @John Set of functions in $\theta$. I should have written $\{cL(\cdot \mid x) : c > 0\}$.

Comment: Oh i c. 
I think I actually deciphered this paragraph due to your explanation! 
Thx!